# Reading Emails in background in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on project that works as dispatcher (Users received jobs in real-time).
Suppose, there is a mailbox that receive tons of emails in every minute.
each email contains some data that must be parsed and send to special user respect to its data.
So, I should read mailbox as faster as I can in background, parse received emails and dispatch a job for each email to users.

Emails data have 4 minute dead-time, So I should not lose any email. each job can be shared between some users, so I used SignalR.

As you know, AppDomain can be shutdown unexpectedly, so my background job maybe lose. I searched and find two blog that gave me some helps, but their released dates was too old (2011, 2013):

[use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive)

[the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)

Since then, many things changed and there are many services that I may not be awared of. Can someone give me any advice about how should I do this in optimized way?!

Comment: Scanning a mailbox to dispatch reports sounds like something that should be running in a dedicated service with a controlled lifecycle, not in-process in an IIS application.

Comment: In other words, a Windows Service would be a good choice. Or a Docker container. Or an [Azure Worker Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me). Or potentially an Azure Function or AWS Lambda invoked by a timer, or a console app invoked by by Windows Task Scheduler.